# SQLite query; Group By Hour And By Device

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a SQLite database of counters and counts like this:

```
       DateTime        |Gate|Count
-----------------------+----+-----
2015-09-23T19:23:01.000|   2|  345
2015-09-23T19:41:08.000|   2|  346
2015-09-23T19:41:30.000|   3|  654
2015-09-23T19:44:00.000|   4|  556
2015-09-23T21:13:47.000|   2|  348
```

I would like to determine the number counted by each gate per hour. In the above table Gate #2 has a count of 1 during the 19:00 hour and a count of 2 in the 21:00 hour.

I managed to get the following select statement:

```
SELECT  strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', DateTime),
          max(Count) - min(Count) 
FROM GateTbl 
WHERE Gate='2' 
GROUP by strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', DateTime);
```

It seemed at first that I was on the right track as this almost did what I want. But it only works for one gate at a time, when I want to return hourly counts for all gates. I've also come to realize that it doesn't work for hours like 21:00 above, where there is only a single entry for that hour.

I can't see a way to do this in a SQL statement and I'm hoping that someone here can. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `But it only works for one gate at a time`. yes. that's what `WHERE Gate='2'` means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add `Gate` to the `group by` and `select`:

```
SELECT gate, strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', DateTime),
       max(Count) - min(Count) 
FROM GateTbl 
GROUP by gate, strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', DateTime);
```

EDIT:

Oops, sorry about that.  What you actually need is the first count from the *next* hour.  SQL has a great function for that, `lag()`.  But not SQLite.  But, you can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
WITH gh as (
      SELECT gate, strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', DateTime) as dt,
             MIN(Count) as mincount, MAX(count) as maxcount
      FROM GateTbl 
      GROUP by gate, strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', DateTime)
     )
SELECT gh.gate, gh.dt,
       COALESCE(gh.next_mincount, gh.maxcount) - gh.mincount
FROM (SELECT gh.*,
             (SELECT gh2.mincount
              FROM gh gh2
              WHERE gh2.gate = gh.gate AND gh2.dt > gh.dt
              ORDER BY gh2.dt
              LIMIT 1
             ) as next_mincount
      FROM gh
     ) gh;
```

The `coalesce()` is just for the last hour.  This uses the last timestamp during that hour.  If there is only one, then you will get 0 for that hour.

Comment: This was hugely helpful. Thank you! But it doesn't address the second issue of getting the counts correct if there is only a single entry for an hour. In the sample table Gate 2 should have a count of 2 for the 21:00 hour but returns 0.

Comment: @IAmNotADBA . . . The key to this is getting the count from the *next* hour.  This means that your hourly counts should aggregate up correctly -- that is, everything will be counted.  The downside is some values that are between rows will be counted in the first hour, when they might have actually occurred in the second, but that is a danger inherent in your data structure.